# Microsoft Office 2016 access to offline documentation

Tags: microsoft-office, help-files

We just got Microsoft Office 2016 installed on a secure system without Internet access. When we try to use Help it tries and fails to go online. How do I get the offline help to work?

(Note I had the same problem with Windows 10, but found the setting to change it pretty easily)

Comment: Offline help is no longer a feature of Office, the last version to have it, is Office 2013.

Comment: can we do something to bring it back? can a CHM help?

Answer (score 0):

Convert older office help files to CHM, then you can access them without needing the old version of office installed. Search for "convert hxs to chm" to find scripts that will do it. Read the instructions carefully. Some precompiled CHM files for VBA were made in 2016 aand can be downloaded here: 
https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/tree/05ff968/VBA/Offline-Docs